# Parse object of array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I got the following from controller :

> {"cat_id":17,"course":"Maths", 
>   "subcat_info":[{"subcat_id":43,**"title":"Test",**"cat_id":17}]}

Now I want to fetch the title of (title:test) from subcat_info.

I tried following foreach in blade view (result is blank)

> @foreach($cats as $cat)
>    {{ $cat->subcat_info[0]->title }}
>    @end

How to get title from this?

Comment: `@end` should be `@endforeach`. What is the output of `{{ dd($cat) }}` inside the loop?

Comment: Sorry I got this from controller 
[{"cat_id":17,"course":"Maths", "subcat_info":[{"subcat_id":43,"title":"Test","cat_id":17}]}]

Comment: Can you share your controller code?

Comment: $cats = Category->with('contentInfo')->get();                                               In model I have used belongs to and has many relation                              I got from Controller  [{"cat_id":17,"course":"Maths", "subcat_info":[{"subcat_id":43,"title":"Test","cat_id":17}]}‌​]                                            I got in foreach                                                                            {{$cat}}      -->>     {"cat_id":17,"course":"Maths", "subcat_info":[{"subcat_id":43,"title":"Test","cat_id":17}]}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$json = '{  
    "cat_id":17,
    "course":"Maths",
    "subcat_info":[{  
        "subcat_id":43,
        "title":"Test",
        "cat_id":17
    }]
}';

$array = json_decode($json,true);
echo $array['subcat_info'][0]['title'];
```

**Output**

Test

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($cats as $cat) 
    {{ $cat->course }} // if you like to print the "title" of the category

    @foreach($cat->subcat_info as $subcat)
        {{ $subcat->title }} 
    @endforeach 
@endforeach
```

Comment: Not Working..
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
error on this line -->>   @foreach($cat->subcat_info as $subcat)

Comment: Can you add to your question the Category model (especially the part where you define the relation to `contentInfo`  and the complete code of the action.